# Rspec/Capyabara - Test appearance and disappearance after few seconds of bootstrap modal (rails, rspec3, capybara 2, webkit driver, bootstrap3)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I would like to test that my bootstrap modal

- appears on page load (A)
- then disappears after 3 seconds (B)
- then if user loads again the page does not load anymore thanks to a cookie based technique. (user should only see once this modal) (C)

Currently, I manage positively to test (A) but not (B) nor (C)

**Code : modal appearance, disappearance after 3 sec and cookie setting it for 720 days (using jquery cookie) without appearing again.**

```
<div class="modal in" id="onboardingModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="onboardingModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <h3 class="modal-title" id="onboardingModalLabel" style="color:#DF2943;">
          title of modal
        </h3>
      </div> -->
      <div class="modal-body">   
        <h4 style="margin-top:0px">
       Theses are the explanations
        </h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // onboard new users with this message
  $(window).load(function(){
    if ($.cookie("onboarding_modal_shown") == null) {
      $.cookie('onboarding_modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show onboading modal once per device
      $('#onboardingModal').modal('show');    
      $('#onboardingModal').fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }
  });   
</script>
```

**Rspec test:**

```
it "sees the modal, then it disappears and if reload it he won’t see it",:js => true do
        visit actual_deal_page_path(:id => @deal.id) 
        # (A) check appearance of onboarding modal the first time
        expect(page).to have_css ".modal"
        within('div#onboardingModal') do
         expect(page).to have_content(‘these are the explanations’)
        end
        # (B) after 3 seconds modal disappears
        ??????????????????
        # (C) user does not see the modal if he loads again the page
        visit actual_deal_page_path(:id => @deal.id) 
        expect(page).to have_selector('.modal', visible: false)
        end
```

Note that for (C), I have a false positive as my test below is ALWAYS passes even if I remove the JavaScript part of the code telling my app to NOT load the modal if the user loads again the page. so my code is also wrong for (C)

thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using wait_until or sleep() ?

Comment: worked with wait_until. can you post answer so that i can give you credit for it (you'll get points) ?